# How to sign in a non existing user? How to make a mock (dummy) user to sign-in Web.Mvc (UI) project that doesn't have a connection string?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

How can I force to log in a non-existing user?

```
[HttpPost]
    [UnitOfWork]
    public virtual async Task<JsonResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginModel, string returnUrl = "", string returnUrlHash = "")
    {
        returnUrl = NormalizeReturnUrl(returnUrl);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrlHash))
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl + returnUrlHash;
        }

        var loginResult = await GetLoginResultAsync(loginModel.UsernameOrEmailAddress, loginModel.Password, GetTenancyNameOrNull());

        //await _signInManager.SignInAsync(loginResult.Identity, loginModel.RememberMe);
        //ClaimsIdentity identity=new ClaimsIdentity();
        //identity.Name = "inanc";
        Authorization.Users.User usr=new User();
        usr.UserName = "inanc";
        usr.Id = 12;



        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(usr, false);



        await UnitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Json(new AjaxResponse { TargetUrl = returnUrl });
    }
```

Forexample this is not working.This throws an error.How can I force to sign in a non existing user.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Maybe we can solve that problem.

Comment: @Caramiriel Thank you for your interest. Problem is easy to explain. Boss would not like to see connection string in config file of Web.Mvc project. So every data transfer including user sign-in and authentication should be made using remote services. If I authenticate user using remote services then I can manually login user to system. That's all. I am trying to login user using remote services.Can you provide any example code ? Thank you

Comment: Do you mean he doesn't want to 'see' the password in the connection string? There are options to use integrated security so passwords in the connection string aren't required.

Comment: @Caramiriel No no..I mean whole connection string. Web.Mvc project should not contain a connection string. Then how can a user sign in the website? This is the problem. Sign-in process should be managed using remote services. And we have another database to store the company user credentials. So both internet users and users from my company can login to the application. I should authenticate the user on remote services and then sign-in the user on Web.Mvc project. So I think I should be able to sign-in the dummy (mock) user in accountcontroller of the Web.Mvc project.

Comment: @Caramirel As a result application will be consist of two parts, Service side (host), and UI side (Web.MVC project). User Authentication process handled in host side and then authenticated user on the host side will be able to sign in UI side. But UI side doesn't have a connection string.

Comment: @aaron  I've spent last two days for just this. But no success. I've pulled last remaining three hair out. This was urgent..

Comment: Create user using `UserManager` and `SaveChangesAsync()` before `SignInAsync`.